# Need a open source Php image gallery script

Tags: php, gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

Can you recommend a php image gallery script which is simple to use, has login system where I can restrict no of downloads of images per user and is search engine friendly.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I use the Veno File Manager ( https://codecanyon.net/item/veno-file-manager-host-and-share-files/6114247 ) its about 3 MB and can create roles (guest, user, editor) in the net are versions warez