# How to do photo management in PHP?

Tags: php, photo

I have a basic script to upload and manage photos, but there are many things that it lacks.

For some reason photo files like .tif do not get uploaded and there is no automatic re-sizing of different images (vertical or horizontal).

Could someone please suggest some solutions for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a open source Php image gallery script.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749258/need-a-open-source-php-image-gallery-script) and a [couple more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gallery+php)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Primage](https://github.com/barbushin/primage) library, it's based on GD2 extension.

Comment: I use the Veno File Manager for me work fine https://codecanyon.net/item/veno-file-manager-host-and-share-files/6114247

Answer (score 3):

http://gallery.menalto.com/

http://www.tftgallery.org/

etc,etc,etc

Comment: Thanks Peter, I am browsing through the documentation for menalito.com and they mention that they require image processing libraries like ImageMagick or NetPBM.  What is the difference between things like menalito and image processing libraries?  Are both typically used together?

Comment: if you are new to that start with a simple one, like tftgallery. as all are frameworks they need some external libraries like ImageMagick. that libaries do the direct image manipulation like resizing, rotation, etc.

Comment: I came across the GD php library which has a lot of useful API functions for image manipulation.  What do you guys think of GD?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I went with the Imagick library.  It has been a few months since I have used it.  There were few minor and solvable problems.  Overall, I am extremely happy with it.

But happy in a kind of a way that I am also fearful that anything breaks because I definitely don't want to go debug it lol :)

But yeah, Imagick works very well - I recommend it to others.